# how to install amazon Corretto 17 on centos

Tags: amazon-ec2, yum, openjdk-17

I need to install jdk 17 on centos7. When I try the yum install, I get the below message

```
sudo yum install -y java-17-amazon-corretto-devel

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * fasttrack: mirror.centos.org
No package java-17-amazon-corretto-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I tried to follow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-17-ug/generic-linux-install.html(Using yum section). When I run the command to import corretto key, it times out.
I tried the yum install -y java-17-openjdk-devel, i get the same error

```
yum install -y java-17-openjdk-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * fasttrack: mirror.centos.org
No package java-17-openjdk-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Did you run the steps before to import the key and setup the repo?  It doesn't make sense that it's going to centos.org still.

Comment: This is the error I get while importing the key.```sudo rpm --import https://yum.corretto.aws/corretto.key

curl: (7) Failed connect to yum.corretto.aws:443; Operation now in progress
error: https://yum.corretto.aws/corretto.key: import read failed(2).```

Comment: It looks like you're behind a firewall / VPN of some sort.  I'd get that sorted out first.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and had a look here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-17-ug/generic-linux-install.html

You need to run the following before installing:

```
 sudo rpm --import https://yum.corretto.aws/corretto.key 
 sudo curl -L -o /etc/yum.repos.d/corretto.repo https://yum.corretto.aws/corretto.repo
```